# Implement Parse's currentUser in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to implement the `PFUser.currentUser` functionality in Realm and I'm getting exceptions thrown when I go to update a field on the current user, specially `RLMException(@"Object has been deleted or invalidated.")`

My current user variable looks like:

```
static var currentUser: User? {
    get { return Persistence.sharedStack.fetch(User.self).first()?.value?.first }
    set {
        if let model = newValue {
            Persistence.sharedStack.insertModel(model)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what's causing the user to be invalidated or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm objects can only every be invalidated in one of two ways:

1. The `Realm` instance at that thread has [`invalidate()`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm10invalidateFS0_FT_T_) called on it explicitly in user code (your code).
2. The Realm object is explicitly deleted using [`Realm.delete(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6deleteFS0_FCS_6ObjectT_) or [`Realm.deleteAll()`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm9deleteAllFS0_FT_T_) by any thread in user code (your code).

So to avoid hitting an "Object has been deleted or invalidated" exception, don't do whichever of the two operations I outlined above that's causing that `User` object to become invalidated and you'll be all set!

Comment: I actually just found the issue after hours of searching through stack traces. I'm using Mappable in conjunction with Moya and I was doing two things: 1) On updating the models I was calling `.toJSON` which is warned about in the Mappable docs, and 2) mapping new objects returned from a network request that didn't yet have a realm. 

Be warned all ye who use Mappable, only call those functions inside a write transition.